# SESSION array does not print there content after page submission

Tags: php

I have a login section in my main page I called this section as a seperated part it contains the following code :

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password = md5($password);

    $users = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'") or $GLOBALS['db']->raise_error(); // Leaving 'raise_error()' blank will create an error message with the SQL
    $users_number = $GLOBALS['db']->num_rows($users);
    if(!empty($users_number))
    {
        while($users_sql = $GLOBALS['db']->fetch_array($users))
        {
            $is_banned = $users_sql['is_banned'];
            // To check blocked users
            if($is_banned == 1)
            {
                $_SESSION['login_error_msg'] = "this users is blocked.";
                header('Location:./'); 
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['first_name'] = $users_sql['first_name'];
                $_SESSION['id'] = $users_sql['id'];
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'true';
                header('Location:./');
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['login_error_msg'] = "Wrong username or password";
        header('Location:./'); 
    }
}
else
{
?>
<table class="fast_login_container">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="login_form" action="./" method="post">
            <table class="fast_login" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <colspan="3">
                        <?php
                            if($_SESSION['login_error_msg'])
                            {
                                echo $_SESSION['login_error_msg'];
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Kullanıcı adı" />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Parola"/>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Giriş"/>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

This code create the login form and when the user enters the email and password I check them in the same page in the php part.
My problem If I have a wrong email or password I should show an error message for that I save the error message in a session variable and call it in the html part after redirecting to the main page(where the login form is).
I can not show the error message. I print the session array befor the header('location:./') and after it ; befor it prints the error message after it does not print any thing.
PS: the `session_start()` is in the header file which I include it as following :

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<body>
    <table class="body_table" border="1">
        <tr><td><?php include_once("include-parts/header_parts.php")?></td></tr>
```

The login part is in header_parts.php .

what should I edit here to get the error messages???

Comment: ``session_start()`` needs to be the first php function to be called before ANY content is sent to the browser ;-).

Comment: It is the first function in my code!!

Comment: There's also no html output before ``session_start()`` is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is php unables to set session just before redirect to other page. You should use session_write_close() before each header("") function. e.g.

```
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $users_sql['first_name'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $users_sql['id'];
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'true';

            session_write_close();

            header('Location:./');
```